# Order of displaying fields using formio

Tags: formio

I am using formio to create form and I successfully created it. But I want to change the order of viewing the fields dynamically. Is there any way to set the order??

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if its the same in the hosted version of Form.io, but in a self-hosted version, the order that the form builder toolbox blocks display in, or the order in which fields display in the edit forms is controlled by the weight property.

```
    this.options.builder = _.defaultsDeep({}, this.options.builder, {
      basic: {
        title: 'Basic Components',
        weight: 0,
        default: true,
      },
      advanced: {
        title: 'Advanced',
        weight: 10
      },
      layout: {
        title: 'Layout',
        weight: 20
      },
      data: {
        title: 'Data',
        weight: 30
      }
    });
```

Changing the weight values will change the order in which those components display.